# Performing math on SELECT result rows

Tags: sql, math, equation

I have a table that houses customer balances and I need to be able to see when accounts figures have dropped by a certain percentage over the previous month's balance per account.

My output consists of an account id, year_month combination code, and the month ending balance.  So I want to see if February's balance dropped by X% from January's, and if January's dropped by the same % from December.  If it did drop then I would like to be able to see what year_month code it dropped in, and yes I could have 1 account with multiple drops and I hope to see that.

Anyone have an ideas on how to perform this within SQL?

EDIT:  Adding some sample data as requested.  On the table I am looking at I have year_month as a column, but I do have access to get the last business day date per month as well

account_id  |  year_month  |  ending balance

1           |    2016-1    |   50000

1           |    2016-2    |   40000

1           |    2016-3    |   25

Output that I would like to see is the year_month code when the ending balance has at least a 50% decline from the previous month.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: We are using SQL server

Comment: could you please post some sample data and desired output?

Comment: Adding sample data and output to original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would recommend making Year_Month a yyyy-mm-dd format date for this calculation.  Then take the current table and join it to itself, but the date that you join on will be the prior month.  Then perform your calculation in the select.  So you could do something like this below.

```
SELECT x.*, 
       x.EndingBalance - y.EndingBalance 
FROM Balances x 
INNER JOIN Balances y ON x.AccountID = y.AccountID 
                     and x.YearMonth = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, x.YearMonth) - 1, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.Will this approach automatically pull up all subsequent months or will it require a join per month that I need to go back in time to look at?

Comment: It will pull up all months.  If you are going all the way to the start of your history, you may need to change it to LEFT JOIN so that the first month is not excluded since there wouldn't be a month prior to the first month to join to.